# How to pairs the elements of two vectors in R

Tags: r

I would like to pair elements of two vectors in R. The order is important.

```
For example, 

    X= c(1:3)
    Y= c(1:3)
I expect to have:

1 1
1 2
1 3
2 1
2 2
2 3
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

I would like to use 'lapply'. My data is more complicated but the idea is the same. I just need to pair each element of the first vector with all element of the second vector.

Comment: `expand.grid(Y,X)[2:1]`, it's much easier and more direct than `lapply`. (The only reason I am doing `Y` before `X` and `[2:1]` is because `expand.grid` is "busiest" in left-most column(s), see `expand.grid(X,Y)` to see; I'm doing this because you said order is important, and I'm inferring column-order too.)

Comment: Why no `1, 1` or `3, 3`?  Also, because you use `1:3` in both vectors, it is not clear from where each digit is obtained.  What, for example, is your expected output from `x <- 1:3; y <- 4:6`?  I think you need to provide more explanation of how to obtain your expected output.

Comment: @r2evans, normally I would agree, but the "missing" combinations in OP's expected output mean that `expand_grid` is only a starting point.

Comment: @Limey  yes, I need 1, 1.sorry. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Limey, I thought the same thing and assumed a typo ... was waiting for Alice to pipe in and correct me :-)

Comment: With OP's edit, `expand_grid` is *definitely* the easiest way to go!

Comment: @r2evans there was a typo. I have edit my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If *"order is important"* means that the "monotonic increase" is important, then simply

```r
expand.grid(X, Y)
#   Var1 Var2
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    1
# 3    3    1
# 4    1    2
# 5    2    2
# 6    3    2
# 7    1    3
# 8    2    3
# 9    3    3
```

However, if column-order (second column increments before first), then just reverse the order of arguments (inferring that the real problem has differing numbers) and reorder them post-function:

```r
expand.grid(Y, X)[2:1]
#   Var2 Var1
# 1    1    1
# 2    1    2
# 3    1    3
# 4    2    1
# 5    2    2
# 6    2    3
# 7    3    1
# 8    3    2
# 9    3    3
```

The column names are inferred from the arguments, so `expand.grid(X=X, Y=Y)` will name them `X` and `Y` instead of `Var#`.

Comment: Amazing help. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

In `tidyverse`, we can use `expand_grid`

```
library(tidyr)
expand_grid(Y, X)
```

---

Or use `crossing`

```
crossing(X, Y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a data table solution:

```
library(data.table)
CJ(X, Y, unique = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
   X Y
1: 1 1
2: 1 2
3: 1 3
4: 2 1
5: 2 2
6: 2 3
7: 3 1
8: 3 2
9: 3 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option is `outer` (but not as straightforward as `expand.grid`)

```
> do.call(rbind, c(t(outer(X, Y, Vectorize(function(x, y) list(c(x, y)))))))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    2
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    2    1
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    3    1
 [8,]    3    2
 [9,]    3    3
```

---

Or we can use `lapply` like below

```
> unname(do.call(rbind, lapply(X, cbind, Y)))
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    1
 [2,]    1    2
 [3,]    1    3
 [4,]    2    1
 [5,]    2    2
 [6,]    2    3
 [7,]    3    1
 [8,]    3    2
 [9,]    3    3
```